# Latex \keywords{} repeating keywords bug

Tags: templates, ieee-style, keywords

I'm using an IEE conference latex model, and when I try to add keywords by using

```
\keywords{ADAS, Smartphones, Data recording device, Road segmentation, Intelligent vehicles.}
```

After my `\end{abstract}`.
When I compile, here's what I get in the pdf:

> Index Terms—DAS, Smartphones, Data recording device, Road
>   segmentation, Intelligent vehicles.DAS, Smartphones, Data recording
>   device, Road segmentation, Intelligent vehicles. A

Any idea what is wrong ?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a minimal example?

Comment: As Dr. Vinnie Boombatz would say, "Don't do that!"

Comment: Sorry, what kind of example ?

Comment: Minimal Working Example is short, complete document, which we can copy in test on own computers and which reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time trying to solve, here is the solution:

Instead of using the:

```
 \keywords{ADAS, Smartphones, Data recording device, Road segmentation, Intelligent vehicles.}
```

The correct use in this case is:

```
\begin{keywords}
ADAS, Smartphones, Data recording device, Road segmentation, Intelligent vehicles.
\end{keywords}
```

It probably has to deal with the template settings. The strange thing is that the first syntax worked as well, but, for some reason, repeated the keywords.

*Hope it helps someone.*